# Android startActivityForResult destroys main activity and closes app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

From within a fragment there are these methods which are used to select and image:

```
private fun pickImage() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    startActivityForResult(intent, pickedPhoto)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == pickedPhoto && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) return
        val uri: Uri = data.data ?: return
        profileImageSelected(uri)
    }
}
```

When the image picker intent is launched, and I press the back button the whole app closes, or if i select an image the app closes.

Should the launching fragment/activity not remain open on the back stack after launching this intent? How do I keep MainActivity from being destroyed?

Edit last lines of log

```
D/AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 3675 for frameCount 11025
W/AudioTrack: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
    See the documentation of AudioTrack() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
D/MediaCodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting dataspace on output surface to #102
I/NavController: Ignoring popBackStack to destination exabyte.hydroid:id/nav_start as it was not found on the current back stack
I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
    Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x8e26a2a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x8e1f03b0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x8e26a2a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x8e1f03b0)
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout (exabyte.hydroid.hydroidlib.fragments.MediaFragment received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be cleared to prevent leaks)) with key bf51f7a1-39d0-4da8-84ff-ef52561804eb
V/TedPermission: permissionResult(): null
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x8e26a2a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x8e1f03b0)
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 4ed2dd07-1b08-4103-aff6-4a2688dfb19c
    Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 672bded5-c266-448c-8858-588bf494c121
    Watching instance of androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment (androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key fd416328-8693-4c43-84ef-6515d121af2d
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of exabyte.hydroid.hydroidlib.activities.MainActivity (exabyte.hydroid.hydroidlib.activities.MainActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback) with key f0e11954-0e32-4bf1-bcb8-8dfd38215b4b
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of android.widget.ScrollView (exabyte.hydroid.hydroidlib.fragments.AccountFragment received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be cleared to prevent leaks)) with key 39854ce8-f98f-46cd-a2d4-584e7cf44894
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView (androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be cleared to prevent leaks)) with key c7f94230-f1ee-4eac-9655-df90c0b71efb
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel (androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 43bcf2fc-5cd7-4b31-9c46-c8e507ab2476
    Watching instance of androidx.navigation.NavControllerViewModel (androidx.navigation.NavControllerViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 1558d440-3c9f-4d6e-9f66-4a04580ceb73
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 82dc1c98-2978-434f-9c97-6340b8952bc9
    Watching instance of androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel (androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 5b8bf7a7-4ee9-43d8-bcae-b6807446cdae
    Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 4db6107f-fca0-4332-86e0-c9942633ee40
    Watching instance of androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel (androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 3cec168f-5059-4140-ac29-01eedc6c2f0e
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key c46cb02a-aaed-42ef-ab38-dbe0624d3bb7
    Watching instance of com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment (com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key 6286e540-9c95-4ed9-a2f2-29b2f26a62f8
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of exabyte.hydroid.hydroidlib.fragments.AccountFragment (exabyte.hydroid.hydroidlib.fragments.AccountFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key 265a7097-4a95-4be2-8f0c-979a24df0be4
    Watching instance of androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel (androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key b23efeb4-f971-4901-8ed3-1ddc1dcc80fd
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key c11be0d2-a9de-43c6-b556-5be59d51e29b
D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0x822ef808, reason disconnectFromSurface
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of exabyte.hydroid.hydroidlib.fragments.MediaFragment (exabyte.hydroid.hydroidlib.fragments.MediaFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key 94533452-9584-4058-88d6-8733178e7132
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment (androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key 77b8ee9a-333e-4b81-8b2f-e51be531c462
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel (androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 7e7e3b97-0918-426c-8fe7-736790de37f5
    Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 04f8cb1f-d509-4247-a83c-86283d8e880d
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment (com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key 9b35fb2c-996a-4d41-8ad5-f87a3f684444
D/exabyte.hydroid.hydroidlib.activities.MainActivity: destroying main activity
D/LeakCanary: Scheduling check for retained objects in 5000ms because app became invisible
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 21903b67-18ca-4ce5-8519-8f0489649f7a
    Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 18b883ba-b439-4a73-b895-4cf82fffdf20
    Watching instance of androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment (androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key d9838d35-fa3f-4ee2-a273-c95db2dbec82
D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity (com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback) with key d3193781-66a3-497d-a5cf-ea71e4a04466
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8d86b00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x90316390)
D/LeakCanary: Ignoring request to check for retained objects (found new object retained), already scheduled in 111ms
D/LeakCanary: Ignoring request to check for retained objects (found new object retained), already scheduled in 108ms
    Ignoring request to check for retained objects (found new object retained), already scheduled in 108ms
D/LeakCanary: Ignoring request to check for retained objects (found new object retained), already scheduled in 96ms
D/LeakCanary: Ignoring request to check for retained objects (found new object retained), already scheduled in 96ms
D/LeakCanary: Ignoring request to check for retained objects (found new object retained), already scheduled in 93ms
D/LeakCanary: Ignoring request to check for retained objects (found new object retained), already scheduled in 38ms
D/LeakCanary: Ignoring request to check for retained objects (found new object retained), already scheduled in 33ms
D/LeakCanary: Ignoring request to check for retained objects (found new object retained), already scheduled in 29ms
I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Explicit
I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 16.231ms for cause Explicit
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8d86b00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x90316390)
I/zygote: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 323(39KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 1.865ms total 63.287ms
D/LeakCanary: Check for retained object found no objects remaining
```

Comment: Show the relevant lines from the logcat.

Comment: On some devices, the image picker requires so much memory that Android will close your app. Upon return from the image picker, Android will restart your app. However, it is also possible that your app is crashing. Please check the logcat for exceptions and post the relevant exception with stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Android OS can kill your activity at any moment when it is not the top activity. Use onSaveInstanceState to keep the state.

Comment: I log in onDestroy of the activity and it is being destroyed when the image picker is opened. There doesn't appear to be any obvious exception in the log cat.

Comment: Your app closes without exception. That is normal. But then.. later Android tries to restart your app/activity. So maybe you have to look in onCreate instead?

Comment: I added some log messages in onCreate and also in onStart and onResume but none are called after the activity is destroyed and the back button is pressed